# Как лучше работать с большими файлами (~500 MB)

Tags: файлы, c++

Ребят, что лучше использовать при работе с большими текстовыми файлами `fopen`, `fstream` или `winAPI`

Comment: Чистый WinAPI и текстовые файлы? Месье знает толк в извращениях.

А если серьёзно, размер файла вообще не при чём. Расскажите, какая у вас задача.

Comment: @VladD, именно чистый WinAPI упомянут не был :)

Comment: Зависит от задач и конфигурации ПК, где будет все работать. В конце-концов если речь идет про работу с текстовыми файлами никто не мешает читать в `std::vector<std::string>`...

Comment: для начала напишите так, как можете. Может скорость и удовлетворит. Проблемы могут начаться только когда размер файла будет равен 2 гигабайтам (а использоваться 32 битные функции).

Comment: Лучше использовать \*nix, а не винду.

Comment: @Flammable: э, а последнее слово в вопросе? (там, правда, про чистоту не было, но использовать WinAPI вперемешку с <fstream>-классами — ещё большее извращение, не находите?

Comment: @VladD, разве в STL есть memory-mapped files?

Comment: @avp, а еще линукс не зависает и для него нет вирусов, ога.

Comment: @Flammable: насколько я помню, нету, а что?

Comment: @VladD, то, что если они нужны, получится та самая смесь STL и WinAPI (в которой, кстати, нет ничего ужасного, если вы не угораете по кроссплатформенности).

Comment: @Flammable: я бы использовал [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) и не заморачивался с WinAPI. А то как превратить `HANDLE` в `ifstream` я, признаться, не знаю.

Comment: @Flammable, просто (насколько я слышал об этом) \*nix-ы лучше, чем винда  работают с большими файлами (по сути с файловым кэшем и памятью, выделяемой процессам).

Но, безусловно, все зависит от задачи. Нам же не рассказали, что предполагают делать  с этим текстовым файлом.

Answer (score 1):

Если под Windows (а Вы упомянули в своем вопросе по WinAPI), то, например, проецирование файлов на память - довольно удобный механизм для работы с большими файлами. И при этом не нагружающий ОС.